# combine serializer choicefield and serializermethodfield

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have class Person with qualification field.

class

```
QUALIFICATION_CHIOCES = [('mt', 'Matriculation'), ('pr', 'pre_university'), ('gd', 'graduate'), ('pg', 'post_graduate'),
                 ('ot', 'other')]
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    qualification = models.CharField(choices=QUALIFICATION_CHIOCES, max_length=2)
```

serializer

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    qualification = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_qual')
    class Meta:
        model = Person

    def get_qual(self, obj):
        return obj.qual
```

Now i want to want add below line in the above code not able to figure it out as i am using custom field name qual which doesn't exist.

```
    qualification = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=QUALIFICATION_CHIOCES)
```

if i simply add the above line i get the error like *the field is required*.

now how can i accept the input with custom_variable meanwhile check with the choices.

Comment: provide it to the default value if you are not provide then it will be null true and blank true

Comment: thanks for the reply, that validation part i have already taken care, now i just need to know how to combine those two methods.

Comment: what you wany to do in those methods

Comment: i am just trying to combine those two methods. one method SerializerMethodField considers input field as qual instead qualification and serializers.ChoiceField to check whether given input in the defined choices list.

Comment: first Django automatically handle choice validation and there is no need to write second method to validate choice

Answer (score 0):

In serializer you need to add fields in class Meta like this

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    all_qualifications = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_all_qualifications(self, obj):
        return obj.qual


    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = "__all__"
         ------ OR ------+
        fields = ["name","qualification","all_qualifications"]
```